# How to set maui new window to be topmost

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PkYi.jpg)Maui support multiple windows.
i want new window floating to be always on top of the main window

This the window that must be on top always

```
Window CurrentFloatingWindow = new()
{
  Page = new NewPage();
};
Application.Current.OpenWindow(CurrentFloatingWindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: [OverlappedPresenter.IsAlwaysOnTop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.overlappedpresenter.isalwaysontop?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#microsoft-ui-windowing-overlappedpresenter-isalwaysontop)

You can set [IsAlwaysOnTop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.overlappedpresenter.isalwaysontop?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#microsoft-ui-windowing-overlappedpresenter-isalwaysontop) to `true` which means this window will be kept on top of other windows.

If there is more than one window marked as always on top, the window that was last activated or interacted with will be on top.

This can be achieved by setting it in [OnWindowCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-8.0#custom-lifecycle-events). Please add the code below in `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
#if WINDOWS
 builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
 {
         events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
         {
                windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                      var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                      var id = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
                      var appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);
                      var presenter = appWindow.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;                                
                      appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.Overlapped);
                      presenter.IsAlwaysOnTop = true;
                  });

             });
});
#endif
```

Last but not least, don't forget adding namespaces listed below:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;
#if WINDOWS
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Windows.Graphics;
#endif
```

Comment: This work but it is only on top of windows application, if i open main screen i want the child screens to be on top of the main screen all the time. I added the image to my question to clarify. thanks for helping

Comment: @PatrickMolatuoa Thanks for your update, would you mind creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as this would be helpful for me to test it on my side!